# Solving $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}} = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation
$$\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}} = x$$

**My approach:**

Tried shifting the variables into different options, but couldn't get anything out of it. So, please help.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt {a-\sqrt {a+x}}=x$?  And, if so, just square, rearrange, and square again.

Comment: "tried shifting the variables into different options" ... can you show us what you mean with that? Perhaps you are already really close to the solution, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: always get the square root alone on one side and square both sides (do this for each square root). This will get you a polynomial that you can solve.

Comment: What is your question? If it is about solving for $x$, you get a quartic in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a-\sqrt{a+x}=x^2$$
$$a-x^2=\sqrt{a+x}$$
$$a+x=x^4-2ax^2+a^2$$
Consider it in terms of a quadratic in $a$
$$a^2+a(-2x^2-1)+x^4-x=0$$
Now we see that $x^4-x=x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(x^2-x)(x^2+x+1)$. And $(x^2+x+1)+(x^2-x)=2x^2+1$. By Vieta, its roots are $x^2-x$ and $x^2+x+1$. You could also do it using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$a-\sqrt{a+x}=x^2$$
$$a-x^2=\sqrt{a+x}$$
$$a+x=x^4-2ax^2+a^2$$
$$x^4-2ax^2-x+a^2-a=0$$
$$(x^2+x+1-a)(x^2-x-a)=0$$

You can factor the last expression by setting up $(x^2+px+q)(x^2+rx+s)=x^4-2ax^2-x+a^2-a$. And comparing the coefficient to find $p,q,r,s$.

Comment: Some roots will be spurious, so they should be checked.

Comment: @J.G. Yes I leave the easy part to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{a+x}=y\ge0\implies x=y^2-a$

$$y^2-a=\sqrt{a-y}\ge0\implies  y^2\ge a$$

$$(y^2-a)^2=a-y\iff a^2-(2y^2+1)a+y^4-y=0$$

$$a=\dfrac{2y^2+1\pm\sqrt{(2y^2+1)^2-4(y^4-y)}}2=\dfrac{2y^2+1\pm(2y+1)}2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x+a$ to rewrite the nested radical equation $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}} = x $ as
$$t-a- \sqrt{a-\sqrt t}=
0$$

Avoid extraneous solutions from squaring the equation and instead  factorize it as

$$(\sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+\sqrt t)(\sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+1-\sqrt t)=0$$
Note that $ \sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+\sqrt t>0$ and any solutions result from
$$ \sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+1-\sqrt t =0$$
which factorizes as
$$\left(\sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+\frac{1+\sqrt{4a-3}}2\right)
 \left(\sqrt{a-\sqrt t}+\frac{1-\sqrt{4a-3}}2\right)=0
$$
Again, the first factor is positive, permitting no solutions, and the second factor yields the sole solution

$$ x=t-a= \frac12(\sqrt{4a-3}-1)$$
(Note: the solution exists for $a\ge 1$.)

Comment: I will put, initially, that $a\neq 0$ and $a$ it is not negative from the irrational equation with parameter $a\in\Bbb R$. Hence $a>0$. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano - actually the restriction is $a\ge 1$

Comment: From, please, you take $a \geq 1$?

Comment: @Sebastiano - you may examine the square-root domain of the equation, or simply requiring $x\ge0$ on the solution

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought to the starting point. You have solved the system after to find the domain.